# SublimeHighlight copies cyrillic symbols invalid to rtf

Tags: ms-word, sublimetext3, rtf, sublime-text-plugin

I want to use plugin SublimeHighlight for Sublime Text 3 which can allow me to copy colored and formatted text to Word, but when I choose "copy to clipboard as rtf" or "view as rtf" I get invalid cyrillic (also arrow symbol) symbols when pasting to Word.

From

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Заголовок Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>Включите JS</noscript>
    <script>
        //пример
        // → 61.67
        // → 54.56
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ð—Ð°Ð³Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ðº Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>Ð’ÐºÐ»ÑŽÑ‡Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ JS</noscript>
    <script>
        //Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð¼ÐµÑ€
        // â†’ 61.67
        // â†’ 54.56
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I choose the "copy to clipboard as html" or "view as html" symbols stay right but formatting I need is lost. So it is not good for me either.

Question: How is it possible to copy text from Sublime Text to Word (rtf) keeping the right characters and right formatting?

Comment: This would best be addressed by opening an [issue](https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight/issues) in the package's repo on Github - it's not anything we can help you with.

Comment: looks like it has already been reported as an issue here: https://github.com/n1k0/SublimeHighlight/issues/44

Comment: At least I can see that it is nothing I can do for now...